# Calculating a sum on an integer column when another column includes the year criteria for the calculation

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I have a spreadsheet where the columns contain values as follows:

```
Column(A)       B            C       D     E  

NameA        01/02/2010      5       4     5  
NameB        05/06/2011      4       3     2  
NameC        12/11/2010      3       5     3  
NameD        08/14/2012      4       4     4  

-------------------------------------------------  

SUMMARY            2010      8       9     8  
                   2011      4       3     2  
                   2012      4       4     4
```

and so on...

I want to calculate the total of column C where the Year in column B = 2010 (or 2011 or 2012, etc.) and create a summary table (possibly in another worksheet) accompanied by a chart.

I have looked at SUMIF, SUMIFS, and SUMPRODUCT.

I would like to know the best way to accomplish this task, preferably to capture the summary in a separate worksheet.

Comment: Could you explain better what exactly you need to do? Because to me, quickly like that, it sounds like you only need to do a normal sum and then set the cell as a normal number. Also, a screenshot of the table would be great, because it's not exactly easy to visualise a table that's as text like this.

Comment: I actually need to determine the average.  I will put together a better question and resubmit with a screenshot of my data.

Comment: Don't resubmit. Edit the question. Mods here hate duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

A **Pivot Table** could do what you want.

Here are tutorials to group by date: 
http://www.databison.com/index.php/pivot-table-quick-tip-group-by-year-quarter-month-and-date-field/ 
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XR8x58Le0HA

Answer (score 1):

Let’s say that the years are in `B97:B99`.  Then set `C97` to

```
=SUMIFS(C$1:C$4, $B$1:$B$4, ">="&DATE($B97,1,1), $B$1:$B$4, "<"&DATE($B97+1,1,1))
```

… adjusting the `1` and the `4` to reflect the location of your data.  This says add (sum) the values in column `C` for the rows where the value in column `B` is ≥ January 1 of the year indicated by the number in cell `B97` but < January 1 of the subsequent year. 
Then drag/fill down to row `99` and out to as many columns as you need.  Of course this can go into a separate worksheet; just use the `Sheet1!` notation.

---

#### Edit

If you wanted an average of these data, you could do

> `=SUMIF(`*args as above*`) / COUNTIF(`*2nd through 5th args*`)`

If you want to handle the possibility that there are no data for a given year (so the COUNT would be zero, resulting in a division by zero error), do

> `=IFERROR(`*SUMIF/COUNTIF formula, from above*`,` *value to display if error*`)`

Comment: I should have been more clear in defining the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely a Pivot Table is the way to go here. Sum column C by dragging it to the Values area and summarise by rows for column B by dragging that to the Rows area.

Then the trick to get where you need is to Group your rows - because they are dates, Excel will give you useful options such as by year, month, etc. Right click a row heading (ie a date), choose Group > select Year and unselect all others so you end up only with a summary by year.

Job done.

Add a chart using the PT as a data source and you should get a simple result.

Then go learn lots of other cool stuff you can do with PTs, such as add filtering, use slicers and stuff like that.

PS: consider making your source data into a Table if you want the PT to still work when you add more data later.